7inch raspberry pi touch screen with aosp 13 size problem
I’m working on a project using a Raspberry Pi 4 with a custom Android 13 ROM and the official 7" Raspberry Pi touchscreen.
The touchscreen display is zoomed in, causing part of the display to be cut off and not fit the screen properly. The resolution settings do not seem to address this issue.
here is my config.txt file:
    kernel=Image.gz
    arm_64bit=1
    dtparam=audio=on


    # The functional overlay
    dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d-pi4-overlay,cma-256

    # Touchscreen and backlight overlays
    dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406-overlay 
    dtoverlay=rpi-backlight-overlay

    #dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dsi-7inch-overlay,sizex=800,sizey=480

    # Additional settings
    #dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral
    initramfs ramdisk.img followkernel
    enable_uart=1
    disable_overscan=1
    #overscan_left=16
    #overscan_right=16
    #overscan_top=16
    #overscan_bottom=16

    display_rotate=0

    # Enable the DSI display
    ignore_lcd=0
    display_default_lcd=1


    # Display settings
    framebuffer_width=800
    framebuffer_height=480
    gpu_mem=256

    hdmi_group=2
    hdmi_mode=87
    hdmi_cvt=800 480 60 6 0 0 0
    dtparam=spi=on`

NB: both vc4-kms-v3d-pi4-overlay (white screen) and vc4-kms-dsi-7inch-overlay ( correct dtbo file generation problem or blocked in splash screen step) did not work for me that's why i am working with vc4-fkms-v3d-pi4-overlay,cma-256 overlay
also tried with
    wm size 

command but it did not solve the problem
enter image description here
i tried to modify the dts file to fix the resolution from there but i had issues with generating the dtbo file there were multiole warnings and errors
i tried with the wm size method also did not work
also tried to modify the config.txt file but for nothing
